# EF Core & Automapper. Mapping one-to-many

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm currently using AutoMapper on an Project running database-first (mysql) Entity Framework.

I have the object 'Alojamiento' that has many 'AlojamientoIdiomas', and 'AlojamientoIdiomas' has one 'Alojamiento'.

I have the foreign key 'fk_idioma_aloj' in 'AlojamientosIdioma' that referes to 'Id' (Alojamiento).

Here is the entity created by Entity framework:

```
public partial class Alojamiento
{
    ...Data (nothing related to AlojamientoIdioma)...
}

public partial class AlojamientosIdioma
{
    public int IdAlojamiento { get; set; }

    public int IdIdioma { get; set; }

    ...Data...

    public virtual Alojamiento IdAlojamientoNavigation { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual Idioma IdIdiomaNavigation { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Here are my DTO's:

```
public class AlojamientoDto : AlojamientoInfoDto
{
    ...Data...

    public ICollection<AlojamientoIdiomaDto>? AlojamientoIdiomasDto { get; set; }
}

public class AlojamientoIdiomaDto
{
    public int IdAlojamiento { get; set; }

    public int IdIdioma { get; set; }

    ...Data...

    public IdiomaDto Idioma { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I want that 'AlojamientoDto' has the property: 'AlojamientoIdiomasDto' be filled with all corresponding 'AlojamientoIdiomaDto' with Automapper but i dont know how, i only see that i have the reverse filling: 'AlojamientoIdioma' has his corresponding 'Alojamiento'.

Maybe i created wrong the foreign key?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543213/how-to-use-auto-mapper-for-nested-objects) question (it's old but looks like it still applies).

Comment: Can you please provide a full [mre]? For example @github.